# how to set schemaLocation in xsd?

Tags: xml, xsd

So here is my basic project layout

```
--package1
  |---package2
      |----One.xsd
  |---package3
      |----Two.xsd
  |----Three.xsd
```

So the question is the following: 
I can access One.xsd from Three.xsd by setting schemaLocation="package2/One.xsd"
But I have no clue how can I access One.xsd from Two.xsd or vice versa.

Comment: What do you mean, "access"? "schemaLocation" is only a hint.

Comment: I mean get access to types specified in the imported schema into another schema.

Comment: You use `<xs:import>`, `<xs:include>` and/or `<xs:redefine>` for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried this myself, but `schemaLocation="../package2/One.xsd"` might work.

Comment: @user2508615 when you say "didn't work", what do you mean? what environment? what XML/XSD parser or processor are we talking about here? What was the exact error message you were getting? etc.